# Any idea why my typography components render normally in localhost, but not on my aws?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, typography

I am using typography component for my headings, but they do not render normally when I publish the website. The styles also do not get rendered. It shows normally in npm run dev. but when I push it and build it on aws, is doesnt show correctly.

[image: How it is rendered on aws]

[image: localhost rendering]

```js
 <Typography className={cardStyles.heading}>
        Rent a room or the whole place
      </Typography>
```

```css
.heading{
    font-size: 22px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black ;
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 10vw; 
    margin-left: 10vw;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 100vw;


}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the same font if you remove `'League Spartan'` locally?

Comment: Open network tab and see if you get any errors

Comment: got an error about the google font i am using

Answer (score 0):

I removed the league spartan font family and used a web safe font and that solved the problem.